# weekly email for enterprise wiki

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-wiki

hi is it possible to send email weekly for an enterprise wiki site in order to mention new pages created in that week to users? I want users to be aware of new pages created that week on wiki enterprise

Answer (score 0):

You could create a site workflow to send weekly alert.

https://jenniferannmason.com/2014/02/24/office365-sharepoint-2013-create-a-weekly-reminder-workflow/

Use REST API to query latest items:

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Mydoc2')/items?$filter= Created ge datetime'2017-11-10T00:00:00.000Z'